# Amazon Redshift to Aurora postgres data migration

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to migrate huge volume of historical data(over 500GB) from production redshift to Aurora Postgres. Production Redshift cannot go down as there are active users during data copy. What would be the best(speed and cost) way to copy historical data ?

Comment: i think the default suggestion in this case is `unload` to s3 & then delete the data from the tables. Would that cause any issues in your situation?

Comment: You can take the snapshot of the current cluster and spin up a new one, from there you can export(unload). So it won't affect your existing performance. Additional cluster is chargeable :)